# properly indent braces with clang-format

Tags: c, clang-format

I'm trying to make clang-format accept the following code indentation:

```
while (condition)
{

}
```

So, I literally tried with one-line in my .clang-format file:

```
BreakBeforeBraces: Allman
```

But I'm always ending with:

```
while (condition)
  {     
  }
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Do you get a different result if you remove your `.clang-format` file?

Comment: I just removed .clang-format and the result is the same.

Comment: That looks more like what I've seen called "ANSI" style.  I think that also matches Google's style guide, for brace placement, anyway.

Comment: So the problem may be that your `.clang-format` file isn't used at all.

Comment: Do you have the `.clang-format` file in the root of your project? If so, can you edit your post with the full contents of the `.clang-format` file?

Comment: Yes it is in root directory. The full `.clang-format` is the one-liner in my first post. I'm using `spacemacs` with `LSP`, I'm currently checking if somewhere another style is loaded.

Comment: The issue was caused by spacemacs or `LSP`. Defining, the configuration variables in `layers` is not enough. `user-config` must also been set. I did it by picking few things at https://docs.doomemacs.org/v21.12/modules/lang/cc/#/configure/configure-lsp-servers/lsp-mode-with-clangd